# why sentence-transformers are not getting installed on my cpu?

Tags: pip, pytorch, sentence-transformers

```bash
$ pip install torch
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch
```

I keep on getting this error while downloading torch for sentence-transformers. What should I do??

I wanted to install sentence-transformers for my project but it doesn't work no matter what I do .